# How do I confirm that two ImmutableMaps have the exact same (key,value) pairs in them?

Tags: java, guava

I need to do this for a unit test. The method being tested returns an ImmutbaleMap and I need to be able to compare it with one that I already have. One way is to get key sets for both(keySets()), run through them and compare the values returned from both maps for those keys. However that to me seems a little inefficient. Is there a better/preferred way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complement to @NPE's answer...

Since your values do not implement `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` correctly, a simple equals on maps will not work; but you use Guava; theefore you have the option of implementing an [Equivalence](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html).

This means, if the class of your values is `Foo`:

- you'll need to implement an `Equivalence<Foo>`:
- your map will have to be a `Map<X, Equivalence.Wrapper<Foo>>`.

With this, you'll be able to use `Map`'s `.equals()`.

You'll have to add values using Equivalence's [`.wrap()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html#wrap(S)) method. See [here](https://github.com/fge/jackson-coreutils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jackson/JsonNumEquals.java) for an example of an `Equivalence` implementation.

Answer (score 6):

If both the keys and the values implement `equals()` correctly, you can simply use [`Map.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> Compares the specified object with this map for equality. Returns `true` if the given object is also a map and the two maps represent the same mappings. More formally, two maps `m1` and `m2` represent the same mappings if `m1.entrySet().equals(m2.entrySet())`. This ensures that the `equals` method works properly across different implementations of the `Map` interface.

If they don't, I doubt you'll find a one-liner that works out of the box. I expect you'd have to implement the comparison yourself. It's not hard to do:

- If the [symmetric difference](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#symmetricDifference%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29) between the two key sets is not empty, you're done.
- Otherwise, iterate over one map, looking up the same key in the other and comparing the values (using whatever comparison method is appropriate).

This can be easily encapsulated into a helper function, perhaps parameterised by the value comparator.

Comment: ... Of course, this requires that both keys and values implement `equals()` correctly ;)

Comment: @fge In my case the values are objects that do not implement the equals() method correctly.

Comment: If they are not implemented correctly in the values then how do you intent to compare them? Equality or not?

Comment: @Shan see my answer for a possibility to use map's .equals() anyway (since you use Guava)

Answer (score 0):

Another choice would be to use plain Map, write impmementation of Equivalence and use following`difference` method from `Maps` class

```
MapDifference<K,V> difference(Map<? extends K,? extends V> left,
                                           Map<? extends K,? extends V> right,
                                           Equivalence<? super V> valueEquivalence)
```

I would prefer this way as it will not alter the Map types (won't do it just to calculate difference or to check equality).

Answer (score 0):

Why should `map1.entrySet().equals(map2.entrySet())` not work?
The `EntrySet.equals()` method refers to the `Map.contains()` method which should work for your values whether they implement `equals()` or not (in this case you probably have an IdentityHashMap underlying).